# Need bulk update when condition doesn't matches

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare
type employee_t is table of employee%rowtype index by pls_integer;
l_employee_data   employee_t;
begin
select *
bulk collect into l_employee_data from employee;
forall indx in 1 .. l_employee_data.count
update roster r
set r.job = l_employee_data(indx).job,
r.position = l_employee_data(indx).position,
r.organisation = l_employee_data(indx).organisation
where r.employee_code = l_employee_data(indx).employee_code;
commit;
end;
```

In the above example, query updates all the data where it matches employee code with idx value. This is fine. My requirement here is, is it possible to update also, the other rows which doesn't matches employee code with idx value? if yes, then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Update *with what*, if employee code doesn't match? If there's no match, then there's no match. You could update those columns with some value, but the question is *which*.

Besides, instead of what you used, consider a single `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into roster r
  using employee e
  on (e.employee_code = r.employee_code)
when matched then update set
  r.job = e.job,
  r.position = e.position,
  r.organisation = e.organisation;
```